# For Loop in Mathematica {n, factored form of x^(n)-1} for 95<=n<=105

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

I am new to mathematica. I am trying to write a for loop to print out {n, factored form of x^(n)-1} for 95<=n<=105.

I have followed the directions of another for loop, and gotten the following code:

```
Clear[x, n]
ls = {};
For[n = 90, n <= 105, n++, ls = Append[ls, x^(n) - 1];
];
Print[ls]
```

However, I don't think this is what I want.  Where did my code go wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: A couple more coding hints: Instead of using `Print[ls];` you can just put `ls` and it will be output (any statement not terminated by a semicolon will be displayed).  Also, in this case you can use `AppendTo[ls,{n,Factor[x^n-1]}]` instead of `ls=Append[ls, ... ]`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `For` loop -- David Stork suggested using `Table`. It is also possible to do the same thing using a "pure function":

```
{#, Factor[x^# - 1]} & /@ Range[95, 105]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Table[{n, Factor[x^n-1]}, {n, 95, 105}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: I think the OP wants `Factor[x^n - 1]` rather than `FactorInteger[n]`.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus:  Yes.  Thanks.